# How to describe data? With p-value or without it?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, descriptive-statistics

I have health related data sets such as age specific mortality of all deaths in specified areas and time periods. Since I have anonymised records for each event, I can calculate indicators of central tendency. Do I need to calculate confidence intervals when describing the whole population included?
Some of my colleagues say that the confidence intervals are needed to avoid an error in a point estimate, another colleague says
that this is not inductive statistics if I do not have a randomly selected sample, but a complete statistical study (including all included subjects from the studied population).
Which approach is more correct and acceptable in the scientific community?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not a matter of correctness or acceptability, because those depend on what you are trying to accomplish.  Is this an historical study for the sole purpose of describing what happened, without drawing inferences about any other time, place, or people; or does it have a larger purpose?

Comment: If you are attempting to generalize the conclusions beyond the values at hand, you don't have a census of the population you're making  inferences about (even if it were a census of some population). You do have some difficulties, to worry about but not the ones you seem to be concerned with. On the other hand, if the conclusions are limited to the values at hand, there's nothing to infer -- you have the population of interest. It may be that you dint have a good basis to obtain a p value in the first case but its a non sequitur in the second. Be clear about what the aim is, before starting.